# Visual Studio Code not formatting due to "Extension 'JSON Language Features' cannot format file" error

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting

I've got an error when trying to format my code in Visual Studio. I have the following plugins installed for the languages I use:

```
shell-format (bash)
Go           (golang)
PyFormat     (python)
```

I have also set up a keybinding SHIFT+ALT+F to format a file, with the when condition:

```
editorHasDocumentFormattingProvider && editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly
```

But whenever I use this shortcut (or use auto-format on save), nothing is formatted and I see this error in the toolbar at the bottom:

**"Extension 'JSON Language Features' cannot format [filepath]"**

I don't know what this extension even is, since I don't have any JSON-based extentions installed.

Has anyone else seen something similar?

Answer (score 2):

I just had this with Python, and it turned out the issue was that I had a line in my settings like this:

```
"editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.json-language-features",
```

Since I wanted Python to use `black`. and it's that that wasn't working and giving me the same error message you're getting, I changed the line above so it was only relevant for `json`, and double checked formatters for other languages (don't forget to check settings for user, remote and workspace).

In the end, my settings for default formatting looked like this:

```
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "[python]": {
        "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
            "source.organizeImports.python": true,
        }
    },
    "[django-html]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": false,
    },
    "[vue]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "octref.vetur"
    },
    "[json]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.json-language-features",
    },
```

And presto, my Python format on save was working again.

I suspect your problem is the same, but post your `settings.json` if making that `vscode.json-language-features` `json` specific doesn't work ...